# Cardinal characteristics without choice

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, axiom-of-choice, large-cardinals, descriptive-set-theory

(I'm taking my definition of a cardinal characteristic from Blass' excellent article http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~ablass/need.pdf, which cites Vojtas/Fremlin/Miller; theirs is more general, but I'm already interested in this more restrictive context.)

Fix a binary relation $S$ on $\omega^\omega$. A set $X\subseteq \omega^\omega$ is *$S$-adequate* if for any $x\in \omega^\omega$ there is a $y\in X$ such that $xSy$. Assuming the reals are well-ordered, the cardinal characteristic associated to $S$ is then the minimum cardinality of any $S$-adequate set. For example, taking $S$ to be domination, $\le^*$, yields the dominating number $\mathfrak{d}$.

My question, roughly, is: to what extent is there a meaningful theory of cardinal characteristics in contexts where choice fails, perhaps very badly?

One approach that seems interesting to me is via "theta-like" cardinals. Recall that $\Theta$ is defined to be the smallest ordinal onto which $\mathbb{R}$ does not surject; see [value of Theta in ZF+AD](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47028/value-of-theta-in-zfad) for some facts about $\Theta$ in the context of $AD$, which is where it is usually studied. We can define analogues of $\Theta$ for cardinal characterstics, as follows: for $S$ a binary relation on $\omega^\omega$ (or similar) we define $\Theta_S$ as the supremum of the cardinals onto which every $S$-adequate set surjects. Assuming $\mathbb{R}$ is well-orderable this is of course equal to the standard cardinal associated with $S$; in the absence of such a fact, this is still a meaningful definition.

(Note that we could also define $\Theta_S$ as the supremum of the cardinalities which inject into every $S$-adequate set, but this seems less natural. For one thing, it is consistent that $\Theta_=\not=\Theta$, which is probably a bad sign.)

---

On to the questions:

> (Q1) Is there work done on cardinal characteristics in the absence of choice, at all?

Note that there is work done - such as Blass' article, as well as Nicholas Rupprecht's thesis http://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/77915/furikuri_1.pdf?sequence=1 - on computability-theoretic aspects of cardinal characteristics. This is really interesting stuff, but I'm looking for something more on the set theory side, ideally actually assigning specific ordinals to relations in a nice way.

In particular,

> (Q2) What can be said about the various $\Theta_S$s as defined above?

Comment: Remember that, under AD, every uncountable set of reals has a perfect subset.  So, unless the binary relation $S$ admits a countable adequate set, every adequate set will map onto every ordinal below $\Theta$.

Comment: Oh wow, that's obvious. I've edited the question.

Comment: People really need to say that AD is a "really bad failure of choice".

Comment: Is this any help for sufficiently simple characteristics: http://settheory.mathtalks.org/andres-caicedo-co-analytic-uniformization/

Comment: I don't think so - certainly if $f$ uniformizes $R$, then $f[\omega^\omega]$ is adequate; but I don't see how this helps provide a lower bound on $\Theta_R$. In particular, there's no reason that - if $f$ uniformizes $R$ - the adequate set $f[\omega^\omega]$ need not surject onto $\omega^\omega$, so it doesn't seem to sharpen the upper bound of $\Theta$ itself. And of course no single adequate set can provide a lower bound: we only know $\kappa\le\Theta_R$ if *every* adequate set surjects onto $\kappa$. So I don't see that this helps, although I could be wrong.

Comment: Alright. I am somewhat stuck. Under AD, how can any $S$-adequate $X \subseteq \omega^\omega$ surject onto $\aleph_1$, since $\aleph_1$ is measurable?

Comment: In $ZF$ alone we can surject $\omega^\omega$ onto $\aleph_1$: map a real $r$ to the countable ordinal $\alpha$, if $r$ codes $\alpha$, and to 0 otherwise. In fact, $\omega^\omega$ maps onto much, **much** larger ordinals if we assume $AD$.

Comment: (Here we view a real $r$ as *coding* an ordinal $\alpha$ if, when pulled back along the Cantor pairing function $i: \omega^2\cong\omega: (x, y)\mapsto{(x+y)(x+y+1)\over 2}+y$, $r$ is the characteristic function of a well-ordering of order type $\alpha$. This is of course merely one of many ways to code ordinals by reals, but they're all equivalent for us. Note, also, that arbitrary countable structures of countable signature can be coded by reals in a similar way.)

Comment: You asked about **adequate** sets, and I answered for $\omega^\omega$ itself; the point is that, knowing that $\omega^\omega$ can surject onto $\aleph_1$ or larger, there's no a priori obstacle to some special subset of $\omega^\omega$ surjecting onto $\aleph_1$ unless we have additional information about that subset (say, we know it's countable). So in the setting of "some adequate set $S$," until we know more about the size of the adequate set, we can't say whether or not it can surject onto $\aleph_1$.

Comment: The source of your confusion seems to be the assumption (true of course in $ZFC$) that "$\omega^\omega$ is not measurable." The problem is, that statement isn't necessarily true, at least not in the way it ought to be: under $AD$ (say), $\omega^\omega$ behaves very much like a measurable cardinal (okay, this is wildly informal, but I think it holds), so there's no reason to suspect that it's "too small" to surject onto a measurable cardinal.

Comment: (Whoops, I just realized that my definition of coding made sense for elements of *Cantor* space $2^\omega$, not *Baire* space $\omega^\omega$. But the point stands.)

Comment: OK, Noah. Thanks for clarifying. I had been thinking along the following lines: pull back the AD-deducible countably complete non-principal ultrafilter on $\aleph_1$ to a similar one, say $U$ on $X$, if $X$ surjects onto $\aleph_1$; now for each $n < \omega$, there is a unique $k_n$ such that $A_n = \lbrace x \in X : x(n) = k_n \rbrace \in U$; take $A = \bigcap_{n \in \omega} A_n$; so $A \in U$. This gives a contradiction.

Comment: Here's what goes wrong. Take $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \aleph_1$ onto (say, as given in my comment) and $U$ a countably complete ultrafilter on $\aleph_1$ via AD (say, the club ultrafilter). Now I can define a filter $F$ as $\{X\subseteq \mathbb{R}: \exists Y\in U(X\supseteq f^{-1}(Y))\}$; however, we can't conclude that $F$ is an *ultrafilter*. For example, if we take $f$ to be the surjection of my comment between $2^\omega$ and $\aleph_1$ and $U$ the club ultrafilter, then neither $\{\gamma: \gamma(0)=0\}$ nor $\{\gamma: \gamma(0)=1\}$ contains the preimage of any $U$-large set.

Comment: In fact, we can *canonically* produce witnesses to the pullback of $U$ failing to be an ultrafilter! This is neat: given a (non-principal) countably complete ultrafilter $U$ on $\aleph_1$ and a surjection $f: [0, 1]\rightarrow\aleph_1$, let $F$ be the pullback of $U$ along $f$ as above. Now define $L=\{r: \{x: x<r\}\in F\}$ and $R=\{r: \{x: x>r\}\in F\}$. Clearly $1\in L$, $0\in R$, and $L$ is closed upwards and $R$ is closed downwards: I claim $L\cup R\not=[0, 1]$. If so, then pick $a\in [0, 1]-(L\cup R)$; neither $\{x<a\}$ nor $\{x>a\}$ are in $F$.

Comment: Fine; thanks, I appreciate the issues much better now.

Comment: (cont'd) So suppose $L\cup R=[0, 1]$. Look at the point $b=sup(R)=inf(L)$: arbitrarily small intervals around $b$ are in $F$, so by countable completeness ($F$ *is* countably complete!) we must have $\{b\}\in F$, a contradiction. So there is some $a\in [0, 1]-(L\cup R)$. In fact, $[0, 1]-(L\cup R)$ (mod endpoints) is a nonempty interval! So we can canonically select the midpoint of this interval as our $b$.

Comment: (cont'd) Putting this together: in ZF we can define a function $g$ from $\{$countably complete ultrafilters on $\aleph_1\}\times\{$surjections from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\aleph_1\}$ to $\{$failures of the corresponding pullback to be an ultrafilter$\}$. So everything is as uniform as could be desired.